# SSL Not Working On NodeBB Forum Apache2

Tags: ssl, apache2, forum, mod-proxy, nodebb

I have a signed SSL certificate on my site, and nodebb isn't working with it. I'm using apache2 and the certificate does work. Would I have to use mod_proxy to make the forum run at a subdirectory instead of port :4567 for it to work? Any suggestions welcome. Thanks.

Here is my config

{
"url": "http://website.com:4567",
"secret": "secret",
"database": "mongo",
"mongo": {
"host": "127.0.0.1",
"port": "27017",
"username": "XXXXX",
"password": "XXXXX",
"database": "XXXXX"
}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a SSL certificate, I got mine from here https://letsencrypt.org/

Then put Nodebb on port 443 and use Apache mod_proxy to remove the port.

SSL now works.